# Containment vs herd-immunity strategies and their mutual (in)compatibility

Tags: covid-19, epidemiology

In the recent Covid-19 outbreak, the UK government's "herd-immunity" approach to mitigate the crisis has received a [lot of criticism](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-51892402). If so many other countries have already decided to pursue a containment strategy, are the latter countries' efforts (to [flatten the curve](https://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/926806) as much as possible) not undermined by a neighbor who pursues such a herd-immunity strategy and consequently allows the curve to be flattened to a much lesser degree? The UK is a country with a great exchange of people to and and from the European continent, the US and China. Does a faithful implementation of a containment strategy require a closing of the border with countries who pursue herd-immunity and who normally do a lot of people-traffic with your country?

I realize that my question has a "biased" or "political" undertone, but I think I have concluded with a question which can be answered in medical terms alone: what say epidemiologists about the compatibility of herd-immunity strategies vs. containment strategies exercised in geographically separated regions (say, assuming the only objective taken into account is to minimize the final mortality count, and with consideration for a country's limited medical resources in a given time-span)?

Comment: The UK has just changed its policy and will now try suppression as well.  Computer modelling suggested that their original strategy of  mitigation would overwhelm the NHS. https://www.stuff.co.nz/national/health/coronavirus/120347837/coronavirus-dutch-embrace-herd-immunity-as-uk-changes-course

Answer (score 1):

The premise of your question is incorrect. The UK Government's strategy is described in [this press conference](https://youtu.be/A0chs7bVQ8Y?t=501) and involves a staged increase in social distancing and quarantine. The plan takes into account the projected epidemic trajectory and data about likely human behaviour under voluntary quarantine.

'Flattening the curve' is explicitly stated to be the main goal of the policy.

Comment: In hindsight: https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2020/apr/29/the-guardian-view-on-herd-immunity-yes-it-was-part-of-the-plan